# How do I use \bmatrix in a subfigure?

Tags: floats, subfloats, matrices

I am trying to put two matrices next to each other with the same caption, but I am having trouble using \bmatrix in the subfigure environment.

Here is the code of what I am trying to do:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]
$\begin{bmatrix}
w_{1,1}   & w_{1,2}   & \cdots & w_{1,m-1}   & w_{1,m}\\
w_{2,1}   & w_{2,2}   & \cdots & w_{2,m-1}   & w_{2,m}\\
\vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots      & \vdots\\
w_{n-1,1} & w_{n-1,2} & \cdots & w_{n-1,m-1} & w_{n-1,m}\\
w_{n,1}   & w_{n,2}   & \cdots & w_{n,m-1}   & w_{n,m}\\
\end{bmatrix}$
\label{fig:weight-mat}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]
$\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}\\
\vdots\\
b_{n-1}\\
b_{n}\\
\end{bmatrix}$
\label{fig:bias-vec}
\end{subfigure}
\caption[Example Connection Weight Matrix with Bias Vector]{Example 
         connection weight matrix with bias vector - the network
         represented has $m$ input units and $n$ output units.}
\end{figure}
```

the error it comes up with when i try to compile is:

```
[15] [16]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   $
l.17 $
      \begin{bmatrix}
```

I think it might be a problem with the subfigure environment, because when I put them in individual figures they compile fine, just one above the other.

I am not desperately attached to using the subfigure environment. If there is a better way to do it, I am open to suggestions - it just seemed like the best way to go about doing what I want to do.

Comment: You need to specify a width in the mandatory argument for each of the `subfigure` environments; something like `\begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}...\end{subfigure}`. It is not clear to me, however, why are you using `subfigure` for each matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a width in the mandatory argument for each of the `subfigure` environments; something like

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}
...
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
...
\end{subfigure}
```

(the `%` after the first `\end{subfigure}` is esential).

It is not clear to me, however, why are you using `subfigure` for each matrix; notice that the `\label`s for each `subfigure` in your example code are useless since no `\caption` was provided beforehand for the subfigures.

You can simply do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{1,1}   & w_{1,2}   & \cdots & w_{1,m-1}   & w_{1,m}\\
w_{2,1}   & w_{2,2}   & \cdots & w_{2,m-1}   & w_{2,m}\\
\vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots      & \vdots\\
w_{n-1,1} & w_{n-1,2} & \cdots & w_{n-1,m-1} & w_{n-1,m}\\
w_{n,1}   & w_{n,2}   & \cdots & w_{n,m-1}   & w_{n,m}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}\\
\vdots\\
b_{n-1}\\
b_{n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\caption[Example Connection Weight Matrix with Bias Vector]{Example 
         connection weight matrix with bias vector - the network
         represented has $m$ input units and $n$ output units.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The `[!h]` specifier is too restrictive; use a less restrictive specifier or none at all.

Answer (score 2):

I worked out a solution to my problem and thought I would post it here in case anyone else had the same problem as me.

I ended up giving up on the subfigure environment and just using the maths environment to format them.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\[ \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
w_{1,1}   & w_{1,2}   & \cdots & w_{1,m-1}   & w_{1,m}\\
w_{2,1}   & w_{2,2}   & \cdots & w_{2,m-1}   & w_{2,m}\\
\vdots    & \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots      & \vdots\\
w_{n-1,1} & w_{n-1,2} & \cdots & w_{n-1,m-1} & w_{n-1,m}\\
w_{n,1}   & w_{n,2}   & \cdots & w_{n,m-1}   & w_{n,m}
\end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}\\
\vdots\\
b_{n-1}\\
b_{n}
\end{array} \right] \]
\label{fig:weight-mat}
\caption[Example Connection Weight Matrix with Bias Vector]{Example
         connection weight matrix with bias vector - the network
         represented has $m$ input units and $n$ output units.}
\end{figure}
```

I would still be interested in how to use the subfigure environment if anyone can solve that problem, because I might need to put captions under two matrices within the same figure at some point, so it would be useful to know how.

Comment: Inside floats, `\label` must always be used **after** `\caption`.